# What is this sound for when starting the engine of an F-15?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, turbofan, engine-starting, f-15

If I remember correctly, to start up old fighters such as F-4s, you need an ASU but it looks new fighters do not need an ASU. Today, I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bpRfx0DT2g). It's a so cool video to know how new fighters start their engines. From 2:38, something starts and make a sound just like woooooooooooooooooo... you think a wolf is howling. From 3:06, the sound becomes stronger but, the question is what kind of starter is used by [P&W F100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F100) that makes such a sound?

Comment: Well, the F-4 normally used an Auxiliary Power Unit, APU (or ASU as you call it), but it also had the capability to use *Start Cartridges" which were pyrotechnic cartridges the size/shape of a gallon can that were inserted into slots in the auxiliary air doors, and when fired, produced high pressure gas to drive a turbine that rotated the engine fast enough to get it started.. But they were prone to misfire and so were used infrequently.

Comment: @CharlesBretana That sounds like an answer!

Comment: Except that it doesn't speak to how F-15s and F-16s do it, which,  I think, (but don't know for sure), is because they have an internal  APU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! finally found the answer. Based on [this](https://www.scribd.com/document/28700771/Jet-Fuel-Starter) and [this](https://www.xflight.de/pe_org_par_lfc_engstart.htm) F-15 uses an APU named Jet Fuel Starter (JFS) which is fitted centrally between the two engines. See 15 on the figure below

[image: Position of JFS]

Another figure of the intake and exhaust of the JFS from bottom of the fighter:

[image: JFS from bottom of the fighter]

The below figure shows the danger area of the JFS:

[image: the danger area of the JFS]

And finally here is an image of this JFS:

[image]

Hope this helps.